# Guide for installing SharePoint 2013, 2016, 2019 on Docker, Hyper-V or VirtualBox

Tags: installation, virtual-machine

I have yet to succeed in installing SharePoint 2013, 2016 or 2019 on VirtualBox, Docker or Hyper-V. I always get to a certain point in the installation then it fails completely. And there doesn't seem to be Docker images to fire up a SharePoint instance at this time.

I am an application developer that is building an app that calls SharePoint On-Premise REST APIs and I need a local test instance of SharePoint. I have been resorting to using Amazon AWS and but it's expensive and I'd like not to do that any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint is not supported in a Docker environment as SharePoint requires a full installation of Windows Server with the Desktop Experience.

Follow the [installation guide for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/install). If you're encountering errors during the install or configuration process, please post those errors so we can further help.

Comment: Trevor - are there known issues with running Linux as the host system, and using VirtualBox Windows Server VMs and running SharePoint 2016 on the VM? the failure is in the prereqs and it seems fairly definite. i unfortunately didn't keep the error i can run it again sometime soon. just checking if you know before i go down that road again.

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of.

Comment: Yeah actually... I'm shocked to say that SharePoint 2019 installed perfectly fine on Windows Server 2016 on VirtualBox. I'm not sure about the older versions of SharePoint maybe I just made a mistake during install... but works great now.

Comment: wouldnt it be ok to have then a docker image with such OS + Sharepoint 2019? You could connect to it by Remote Desktop for instance.

Comment: Docker containers are not VMs.